# ruby shoes - removing minimize and exit buttons

Tags: ruby, user-interface, shoes

I've been looking for any ideas of how this could be done using the Shoes toolkit, but with no great success. Does anyone know at least a point to start from? I am building a small mail client and I need to remove the title buttons for the login window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoes only implements a 'limited tool box', with which you can create your own tools. You can do awesome things with it, but there is a lot of things you canno't do, because it is only a toolbox, by definition.

For instance, you could create buttons with 'close' written in it, and link a bunch of code to close the window.

That would be ugly, but unfortunately, there's no way for the time being on modifying the current title buttons (close minimize maximize) of your environment.

Here is the toolbox -> http://shoesrb.com/manual/Shoes.html